# Netbeans doesn't see class in autocomplete (but it is set in dependency manager set by pom.xml)

Tags: maven, tomcat, netbeans, catalina

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.numbeo</groupId>
  <artifactId>LetsEncryptAcmeChallengeValve</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.41</tomcat.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

I have created it as New Project from Netbeans 12.2, but when I type a new first class:

```
public class LetsEncryptAcmeChallengeValve extends Valve
```

I want Netbeans autocomplete to find me the class from Tomcat

import org.apache.catalina.Valve

But autocomplete is not working see screenshot:
[image: netbeans maven project autocomplete problem]

How to fix this?

Comment: You should define it as a dependency and not in dependencyManagement...

Comment: That seems to be the correct answer. Thank you @khmarbaise